# Defining Two Objects Differently Using One Using Input

Tags: python, dictionary, input

Is there a way to define two objects but with one user input?  To go deeper, there will be multiple preset dictionaries and I want to ask the user to identify which dictionary they want to use.  Then two objects will be set using the input, one will be set to the input as a string (the name of the dictionary) and the other will be set to the dictionary itself.

```
Barney = {"Height": 100, "Weight": 200, "Hobby", "Fishing"}

input("Who do you want to talk to?")
PersonName=input
PersonDict=input{}
print(PersonName, ":about:", PersonDict)
```

```
Who do you want to talk to?  *Barney*
Barney :about: {"Height": 100, "Weight": 200, "Hobby", "Fishing"}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question exhibits no effort to research your issue beforehand, as well as such a lack of understanding of the basics of Python and programming in general that I believe any help I can offer would not help you learn anything. I suggest that you follow a tutorial for beginners such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWRfhZUzrAc) by FreeCodeCamp before attempting to code something by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Make a nested dictionary, where the outer level key is the person's name.

```
people = {
    "Barney": {"Height": 100, "Weight": 200, "Hobby", "Fishing"},
    "Fred": {"Height": 192, "Weight": 157, "Hobby", "Drinking"},
}

name = input("Who do you want to talk to? ")
print(name, ":about:", people[name])
```